# IP tables for ECS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

One will also need to set the following networking commands on your container instance so that the containers in your tasks can retrieve their AWS credentials:

One will also need to set the following networking commands on your container instance so that the containers in your tasks can retrieve their AWS credentials:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 169.254.170.2 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:51679
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.170.2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 51679
```

Can somebody please tell what does this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those settings are needed to allow clients running in ECS tasks to be able to reach the credentials endpoint used to provide [task IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)

The net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet setting is needed to allow the first iptables rule to work. Normally traffic destined for loopback addresses isn't processed by the routing tables, and so won't be seen by iptables POSTROUTING rules.

The second setting is needed to configure netfilter to rewrite TCP traffic originating with bridge-mode containers destined for port 80 of 169.254.170.2 to 127.0.0.1:51679. This is the port on which the ECS agent vends task role credentials.

The third setting is needed to provide the same functionality except for host-mode containers. It affects outbound, rather than forwarded, traffic destined for the task IAM credentials endpoint, and redirects it to the port that the agent actually listens on.